# getting selected item from radio list view. Android

Tags: android, listview, radio-button, selected

I am trying to get the selected value out of a single choice list view and it won't let me use the `setOnItemClickListener` any ideas?

```
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, values);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {
          String selectedFromList = (lv.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt));
        }                 
    }
```

Comment: Try ...(new **AdapterView**.OnItemClickListener() ...

Comment: Define "it won't let me"

Comment: ListView view = (ListView) myView;
 String str=(String)view.getSelectedItem();

Answer (score 1):

modify like this: String selectedFromList = (String) (lv.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt));

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to bind the "onItemClickListener", just use "getCheckedItemPosition" and you can get the checked position. then get the selected item from your data source.